# retopology overlapping problem

Tags: retopology

I'm very confused, I finished my retopology and tried to apply it through the tutorial so then I could rig it, but when I disconnected *In Front* it became "static". Basically its overlapping on each other that's why it looks staticky.

I tried to solve it for weeks but nothings seems to look right.

This is how it looks with and without *In Front* in the Viewport Display

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, once you've finished the retopoogy, apply the Shrinkwrap? Also, what is the Multires for?

Comment: i applied skrinwrap before too but it was the same for some reasons:( Multires to make model appear more smooth i believe (thats what this guy from tutorial used)

Comment: it basically doesn't matter when I'm applying it its still look overlapped on each other and not smooth like staticky

Comment: When you say that it is overlapping, do you mean that the low-poly overlaps the high-poly? I'm not sure what's your problem, maybe share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_38fmx_sGb5LTzBcrXYIGo3kwkUOspHG?usp=sharing this is google drive with my blednder file, thank you so muchT_T

Comment: Your file is too heavy for my computer, it makes Blender crash, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do, once you've finished your low-poly version, remove the Multires and apply the Shrinkwrap modifiers, hide the high-poly version, and you should be good?

Comment: i dont know why i should hide them becuase my sculpture body need to be retopologies with them?

Comment: what do you mean by my sculpture body need to be retopologies with them? You need to create objects that are as low-poly as possible, if you have a high-poly object, the retopology is used to make a low-poly version of the high-poly, once you have finished the low-poly, apply the Shrinkwrap if you've used one, keep the high-poly somewhere in a hidden collection, and you're good?

Comment: oh so just hide main mesh (body) and leave the retopologise version that applied with shrinkwrap and use this ver for riging?

Comment: apply the Shrinkwrap of the low-poly, you can now hide the high-poly (or put it in a collection that you deactivate, you can put it in another blend file as you should not need it anymore unless you need to bake its details), and rig the low-poly

Comment: and whatever you're trying to do, I doubt you need 25M triangles on a character like this

Comment: thank you so much guys!! i feel very dumb but it all works now:)